# How to add class to Walker_Nav_Menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have customized a menu for my header, and this is the code:

```
    class Primary_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        if ( array_search( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes ) ) {
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='dropdown %s'><a href='%s' class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" >%s</a>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes ) || array_search( 'current-page-parent', $item->classes ) ) ? 'site-nav__item--active' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
        } else {
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='site-nav__item' %s><a class='site-nav__link' href='%s'>%s</a>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) ? ' class="site-nav__item--active"' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
        }
    }

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\">\n";
    }
}
```

What I need to do, is I have to give one of my menu item a custom class in the WordPress back-end, Admin area.

I have added the custom class, but it doesn't show up.

That tells me, and also looking at other code, I need some sort of array or class variable and then if there is a class from the back-end wp admin area, then insert it in the li class. Not sure how to do it though.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60168/add-a-custom-class-to-admin-menus

Comment: That's with code however, I need this to be for a person that has no clue what code is - so in the admin back-end being able to add the CSS Class(Optional) in the menu. I know that the walker class needs more works, so it passes the selected or added CSS.

Comment: So you want to create a UI for users to add classes to menus in the WordPress administration?

Comment: That feature is already created. Write in google images this - adding class to WordPress menu

Comment: Take a look at this plugin, should do what you are looking for: https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/